# Can congress end the SAG strike?

Tags: united-states, unions

The Screen Actors Guild recently began a strike, ceasing all work on most productions in the motion picture industry.

Last year in 2022 Congress used the Railway Labor Act to force an end to the strike of the railway workers. Does a similar mechanism exist for Congress to force an end to the SAG strike?

Comment: Its not the same thing.  The Film Industry is not essential

Comment: @RohitGupta I suppose you posted that as a comment and not an answer because it omits a constitutional analysis that leads to the conclusion that the Railway Labor Act is permissible but a hypothetical analogous Motion Picture Labor Act would not be.  I suppose that such an analysis is the answer that Eric Urban seeks.  I'm not in a position to post such an answer at the moment but I know that there are a few regular users of the site who can probably do a good job of it.

Comment: @RohitGupta: Does it matter?  Is Congress's authority here limited to *essential* industries?  If so, why?

Comment: It is elementary that Congress alone can't do anything except in the highly exceptional case of a veto override and even then, the President or an executive branch agency needs to enforce the law in most cases.

Comment: Also of note is that interstate railway is a federal matter under the commerce clause, directly implicating railway workers. Movies are not interstate.